# How to identify instances in array interface?

Tags: java, interface

I have an interface called "Shape" and 2 classes that implements it (Circle,Square).
I also have an array of `Shape` (`Shape shapes=new Shape[20]`).

How do I know which shape (`Circle` or `Square`) is in a specific cell
(which shape is in `shapes[0]`, `shapes[1]` and so on...)?

Comment: `shapes[0] instanceof Circle` or `shapes[0] instanceof Square`, depending on which you want to check for.  `instanceof` checks if the object is an instance of the class.

Comment: In most usecases I could think of you don't actually _need_ to know which type of shape you have (due to polymorphism being used), so why exactly do you need that information?

Comment: Unless this exercise is to help learn Java or programming, I'd use [`Ellipse2D`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/geom/Ellipse2D.html) & [`Rectangle2D`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/geom/Rectangle2D.html) instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned by @jwa you can use `instanceof` for checking the type. Classical solution for processing shapes differently depending on their actual type would be the Visitor pattern:

```
interface Shape {
    accept(ShapeProcessor processor);
}

class Circle implements Shape {
    accept(ShapeProcessor processor) {
        processor.visit(this);
    }
}

class Squere implements Shape {
    accept(ShapeProcessor processor) {
        processor.visit(this);
    }
}

interface ShapeProcessor {
    visit(Circle circle);
    visit(Squere squere);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `instanceof` syntax to check if an object is an instance of a specific class. This allows you to perform different actions depending on what type of shape it is:

```
for(int i = 0; i < shapes.length; i++) {
    if (shape[i] instanceof Circle) {
        System.out.println("Shape " + i " is a Circle");
    } else if (shape[i] instanceof Square) {
        System.out.println("Shape " + i " is a Square");
    }
}
```

Alternatively, if you don't need to do something specific with each type, and you just want to list them:

```
for(int i = 0; i < shapes.length; i++) {
    System.out.println("Shape " + i " is a " + shapes[i].getClass());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by @Thomas you generally shouldn't care. The idea is that all instances implement an interface or extend a common class. You should think of them just as Shapes.

If you want to draw them, put this responsibility inside the class by giving the Shape a `draw(canvas)` method which each class implements. Now you could easily add more Shapes without current code breaking. And each shape knows how to draw itself.

You could go with the instanceof answer provided by @jwa. But in in object-oriented languages instanceof is really a code smell.

Info on instanceof code-smell: http://smsohan.blogspot.nl/2011/11/using-instanceof-is-mostly-code-smell.html

General code smell info: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell

Answer (score 0):

The Simple but a but ugly option is to use `instanceof` operator, as described in another answer. However, think if you can add an abstract method to `Shape` to do whatever it is you need to do.

For more complex cases, this method might actually be a factory method, and return an instance of (a private subclass of) another abstract class or interface like `interface ShapeTransformer` and the Circle class would have `private class CircleTransformer implements ShapeTransformer` etc.

Or use the visitor pattern explained in another answer.

Details really depend on what you want to do. For *some* cases an if-elseif ladder using `instanceof` is fine, as long as you realize it will come back yo haunt you if the code lives longer than you anticipate.